# how to store all the variables from one notebook in a file and use the same variables in other notebooks in ADF?

Tags: pyspark, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have a notebook in ADF which is dependent on get meta data stage to get the file names.
after fetching those file names I'm assigning the path of each file names in specified variables.

I want to use these variables in other multiple notebooks in ADF

how to achieve this?
I cant run the parent notebook in all other notebooks as parent notebook is dependent on get metadata stage and use those variable

Comment: Are your variables string type (path) or a list of strings (list of paths)? Please provide sample data for these variables

Comment: my variables are string type(path)

Answer (score 0):

You can write all the values of the variables into a json or text file from the main notebook and read the file to access these values from different notebooks.

- The following is a demonstration of the same. I have 3 variables, `file1, file2 and file3` (String type containing path to files).

```
print(file1,file2,file3,sep='\n')

#output
dbfs:/mnt/repro/sample_1.csv
dbfs:/mnt/repro/sample_2.csv
dbfs:/mnt/repro/sample_3.csv
```

- Create a JSON file by hardcoding the key name (If variable names are insignificant, you can simply create a string containing all the files seperated by `,`)

```
#data for creating a json file

my_json = {"file1": file1,"file2": file2, "file3":file3}
#{'file1': 'dbfs:/mnt/repro/sample_1.csv', 'file2': 'dbfs:/mnt/repro/sample_2.csv', 'file3': 'dbfs:/mnt/repro/sample_3.csv'}


#data for creating a txt file

text_data = ', '.join([file1,file2,file3])
#dbfs:/mnt/repro/sample_1.csv, dbfs:/mnt/repro/sample_2.csv, dbfs:/mnt/repro/sample_3.csv
```

- Now you can write this data to any required path using the following way.

```
#for json

json_as_string = json.dumps([my_json])
f = open("<path>/variables.json", "w")
f.write(json_as_string)
f.close()

#for text
f2 = open("<path>/var.txt","w")
f2.write(text_data)
```

- Now, you can read these files from any notebook in the following way

```
#for json
f = open("<path>/variables.json", "r")
data = json.load(f)[0]   #data is a dictionary, key value pair

#for text
f2 = open("<path>/var.txt","r")
data = f2.read() #data is string. use split to get list of required file paths
```

Comment: thanks, this helped me to achieve the requirement